# How can this flag be declined? How is this not helpful?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

A few days ago I flagged a comment [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675738/how-to-write-a-code-if-i-want-to-display-thankyou-view-from-localhost-and-my-com).

OP was asked to provide code and they didn't know whether to place it in question or comments. They added this comment:

`sure <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"> <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US"> <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"> <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="<?php echo $shipping; ?>"> <input type="hidden" name="return" value="predragstevanovic.com/webprodavnica/…; <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="predragstevanovic.com/webprodavnica/">; <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="predragstevanovic.com/webprodavnica/paypal.php">; <input type="submit" name="pay now" value="Plati" />`

I mentioned to the OP to kindly move the comment to an edit in their question but also flagged this comment with a reason `Code should be added to question, not comments`.

But why was it declined? Nothing personal but what's wrong with that flag technically?

Comment: I guess it would have been more successful if you had just moved the code to the question, and would have flagged with a "I made the code part of of the question, so this is now obsolete".

Comment: I don't know why the flag was declined, but why didn't you just edit the question yourself, then flag the comment as "obsolete"?

Comment: Because someone else already copied it to code as well, there was nothing more to be done. Except a big comment under the question which was not helpful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your flag just didn't fully describe the situation.

> Code should be added to question, not comments.

Copying that code into the body of the question is something that anyone can do, since anyone can suggest an edit now.  Stack Overflow mods have been buried in flags for the past few months, so we're trying to encourage people to take whatever action they can with the tools they have available before flagging for a moderator to step in.

As Bart and Flimzy mentioned in the comments, you probably should have flagged the comment as obsolete after the edit was complete.

(Having said that, I probably would have marked the flag that you did throw as helpful, since a moderator did need to delete the comment.)